# Referring to the table form on the tab of the main form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have got pretty well-working code for exporting the subform table (MS_table) to the Excel. From the early morning I've been trying to make it work in case when subform table (MS_table) is located on one of the tabs of the main form. I've tried thousands of syntax variants. The collection of tabs is called "Dates", it has two tabs: "Dates" and "Samples". Please, help!

```
With Me.MS_table.Form.Recordset
    For Each fld In .Fields
        nfld = nfld + 1
        app.cells(2, nfld) = fld.Name
        If Me.MS_table(fld.Name).ColumnHidden Then
            r = 0
        ElseIf Me.MS_table(fld.Name).ColumnWidth = -1 Then
            r = 2.499 * 567
        Else
            r = Me.MS_table(fld.Name).ColumnWidth
        End If
        r = r / 567 * (100 / 18.65)
        app.cells(2, nfld).ColumnWidth = r
    Next
End With
app.range("a2:z2").Font.Bold = True
app.range("a3").copyfromrecordset Me.MS_table.Form.Recordset
app.Visible = True
```

Comment: If the code is behind main form, code needs to reference subform through the container control. Put the code behind the subform and don't have to worry about referencing through subform container control. As a subform the code would have to be changed from `Me.MS_table(fld.Name)` to `Me.MS_table.Form.Controls(fld.Name)`. I always give containers a name different from the object held.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! Sorry, but not everything is clear for me from what you've said)) 
it doesn't like this `If Me.MS_table.Form.Controls(fld.name).ColumnHidden Then`
saying that 'object doesn't support this property or method' :(

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about referencing controls, not columns of form in datasheet mode. Did some more testing. Following works (x is a variable holding field name): `Me.MS_table(x)` as well as `Me.MS_table.Form(x)`. Now you need to debug to see if the value input by referencing `fld.Name` is correct. Do field names have spaces or special characters?

Comment: I've checked all the fields, the following works:  `Me.MS_table!IEMAE.ColumnHidden = True` so the problem is with `(fld.Name)` i guess... at the same time this syntax works if the datasheet is not located on the tab... 
No spaces or spec characters!%

Comment: What do you mean by 'datasheet'? Is this a form or table as the container Source Object? I tested your code for both and it works for both. Did have to correct one control name on the form to match the field name. Subform container is on a Tab control. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: It is a tableform based upon query. Hm... Maybe I could sent you the whole database somehow?

Comment: Post to a site that allows uploading and downloading files. Don't think SO has that. I use accessforums.net.

Comment: Here's the link to the database file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-sBVxgnj9OuBd-AvVJyq3d6AXgM9VcMY
Open it with Shift, then enter into visual basic space and find the code for the 'Form_MainUserForm', and then Private Sub btnExcel_Click()
There is another version of code there...

Comment: Sorry, not able to run your code because of language.